# Alpha map to mesh without using SVG

Tags: mesh, texturing, export, transparency

So I made this plant in blender and I want to use it in another program (Zappar) but it only accepts mesh, My plant's leaves are using alpha maps, I wanted to know what would be the best way to convert it to mesh...

I've tried:

- converting alpha map to svg and then to mesh (didn't work, too complex)
- tracing the alpha map with a mesh and extruding... (tds, takes too much time)

My best guess is to create it again using 1 leaf and array modifier...

[image: render]
[image: solid]
[image: alpha map]

Comment: I would suggest the free graphics program Inkscape, trace bitmap feature, and with an inverted image, enable remove backgrounds and save it as a plain SVG. You may not get an answer, as an SVG is really the best way to get this object into Blender, and then use an extrude or knife project workflow.

Comment: I do have Illustrator and I tried using the SVG but it didnt work as well as it did for you.. immana try it again later, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you absolutely cannot get an SVG, you could create a new texture then displace it on a target cube with a modifier in the Z axis.
   [image]

The only problem with this, is that you must cut away the base and find a way of capping the faces.

Update:  I have found a bit of a trick with the modifier stack.  Using the subdivision, displace, and re-mesh modifiers you can cut away the back "plate" of your extrusion.  It will work, as long as the option in re-mesh, "remove disconnected" is checked.

[image]

2. SVG s produce a smoother result.  The cleanest way to do this is to use a program with a Trace Bitmap function to produce the .SVG.  Both Illustrator and Inkscape do this.  So you don't have to manually trace anything.

Inkscape produces a good result when the background is white and the objects are  black, going to Multiple Passes, and checking the Remove Background check box. I found that the cleanest format exporting from it was with the plain .SVG file format.

Here are the results side by side:

[image: co]