Trimming face to texture
I was wondering if there was a simple way to trim a face to a texture, basically an operation that looks at the transparent parts of the texture and divides the face to approximate the texture drawing. I am thinking that likely I will have to do this manually but it would be great if there was an operation for it.
I am trying to modify a model to make it 3D printable so I wanted to trim these faces to match how the texture is and then expand and connect the faces to give them proper dimension for printing.


Short Answer:
To my knowledge, there isn't a trim tool specifically for this. Practically speaking, to get a clean result import an SVG to cut the shape with the Knife Project tool to get the cleanest boundary edge.
Longer Answer
There is a slight exception, we can use the alpha channel for a selection to delete unwanted geometry, provided that there are enough subdivisions in the mesh to get a good resolution.  If we are dealing with a flat surface it helps.
Let's do this experiment.

Make a plane and enter Edit Mode, press7to enter the top view, aselect the mesh, and press u to get the Project from View. Check all the boxes.  Go to the Shader Editor and connect the image texture to the material, a PNG with an alpha channel.

Then add a geometry node tree with the image texture deleting anything that equals the Alpha Channel selection, link the vector socket to the group input, and in the GN Modifier Properties tab pick the cross shape to type in 'UVMap'. This will allow geometry nodes to use the exact same UVMap as the object.   Add subdivision nodes to allow us to get more resolution.


The main ingredient is the (cool) Image Texture Node which has an alpha channel output and the Delete Geometry Node, which we can use for selection.
Here are the results with 4, 6, and then 12 subdivisions.





You get the idea.
The alpha channel edge boundary can be smooth but to delete the selection with the same smooth line, we need a lot of underlying geometry.
Blender 4.4 Alpha


Someone asked if you needed an SVG to create a displacement map, and instead could use an alpha channel.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249843/alpha-map-to-mesh-without-using-svg/250055#250055
